# APS Design Automation - Open Revit Cloud Models

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to follow this Blog Post to adapt Design Automation to support access to Revit Cloud Models

[link to Blog](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/design-automation-api-supports-revit-cloud-model)

My question is how to adapt commandLine to not include rvtFile, since it will be opened by inputJson info (projectGuid/modelGuid). Simply suppress it from the command and from parameters list? Is the data body bellow correct?

```
{
            "id": "UpdateParametersActivity",
            "commandLine": [ "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /al \"$(appbundles[DA_UpdateParameters].path)\"" ],
            "parameters": {
              "inputJson": { 
                  "verb": "get",
                  "description":"input json", 
                  "localName":"params.json",
                  "ondemand": false, 
                  "required" :false, 
                  "zip": false 
              }
            },
            "engine": "Autodesk.Revit+2022",
            "appbundles": [ "ME_BimViewer_DES.DA_UpdateParameters+test" ],
            "description": "Update Parameters from Revit file."
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, skipping the `/i` argument in the command line allows you to not have a document opened by DA for you. Your command line is correct, did you try it?

```
"commandLine": [ "$(engine.path)\\\\revitcoreconsole.exe /al \"$(appbundles[DA_UpdateParameters].path)\"" ],
```

You will have to open the document yourself using:

```cs
var cloudModelPath = ModelPathUtils.ConvertCloudGUIDsToCloudPath(inputParams.Region, inputParams.ProjectGuid, inputParams.ModelGuid);
Document doc = rvtApp.OpenDocumentFile(cloudModelPath, new OpenOptions());
```